# About intermediate fields and cyclotomic extensions

Tags: galois-theory

I'm a bit lost with the next problem

Let $\zeta_9$ a primitive 9-th root of unity. Show that $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q(\zeta_9)}$ has exactly 2 intermediate fields.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: You've tagged this question ''Galois-theory'', so I presume you have the tools of Galois theory at your disposal. What is the Galois group of the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})/\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta_{n}$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity? What information about intermediate fields does the Galois correspondence give you? Answering these two questions should help you answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

what is the Galois group $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{9})/\mathbb{Q})$? If you know Galois theory we will very well know it is $(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. Now us e Galois' Fundamental theorem to conclude that the intermediate subfields are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of the Galois group. Now Analyze the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. Now 
$$(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})^{*} \cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$$.

So, it has two proper subgroups and hence two proper intermediate subfields which are precisely the fixed fields of these subgroups.